# PHP Use foreach on a json string that has unicode emojis in it

Tags: php

I have a database and it stores discord guilds in it and the discord guilds can have emojis like   and • . I am having an issue though when I am trying to do a foreach on the data it just says

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /path/to/my/php/file

I just want to either entirely remove all emojis/unicodes or just be able to show them normally within the foreach statement without a ton of work.

Foreach im using

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT guilds FROM users WHERE discord_id = :discord_id");
$stmt->bindParam(':discord_id', $userdata['discord_id']);
$guildData = $stmt->fecth(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$guildData = json_decode($guildData, true);
var_dump($guildData);

foreach($guildData as $g) {
    echo $g;
}
```

Sample of the data that is in the column guilds:

```
[{"id": 1, "guildname": "Server Name "}, {"id": 2, "guildname": "Server Name"}]
```

I want to either keep them and show all the emojis or just entirely remove all unicode emojis and symbols.

Comment: You need to post the actual code, not just the error message.

Comment: Its just a normal foreach ill add in the main post

Comment: Well the error is because `$guildData` is a string, not an array or other iterable construct. What exactly are you trying to do here? Did you mean to do a `json_decode()` instead of the `json_encode()` you've written there? `true` is not an argument I'd imagine anyone would want to feed in as an encode flag.

Comment: Ive tried decode, encode nothing works where it actually will display the names with the emojis/unicodes inside of the echo...

Comment: Let me guess, the emojis all come out looking like `ð¶` or similar?

Comment: No it just gives me that error the foreach doesn't even work, even just using print_r($userdata['guilds']) doesn't even work.

Comment: If you do in mysql: `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM users where Field='guilds';` what is the exact Collation for it?

Comment: https://sevy.i.purplemen.net/2vfCQpnEmMuy.png Is what I get from that. Ive tried changing it back to json as the type but it wont allow me to anymore id prefer to have it as json but just was trying if changing to long text would work since it wouldnt let me put that collation for json type

Comment: @Severingcastle8 Please [edit] your question to include the current (fixed) source code you have. Also include `var_dump()` lines between loading the data and the `foreach()` loop. Add the output you get from these additional `var_dump()` lines to your question.

Comment: I dont have fixed code nothing Ive done actually works for the foreach....

Answer (score 0):

OK I still haven't been able to figure out what you're actually trying to accomplish, but what *is* clear is that you don't know what your data looks like and you're fumbling in the dark trying to apply random functions and hoping that something sensible comes out of `echo`.

Use [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). It will tell you exactly what something is down to the smallest detail. For example, `var_dump($userdata['guilds']);` will tell you exactly what that variable *actually* is and let you make an *informed* decision about what to do with it next.

Eg:

```php
$input_json = '[{"id": 1, "guildname": "Server Name "}, {"id": 2, "guildname": "Server Name"}]';
$decoded = json_decode($input_json, true);

var_dump($input_json, $decoded);
```

Output:

```
string(83) "[{"id": 1, "guildname": "Server Name "}, {"id": 2, "guildname": "Server Name"}]"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["guildname"]=>
    string(16) "Server Name "
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["guildname"]=>
    string(11) "Server Name"
  }
}
```

So now I know I should be able to:

```php
foreach( $decoded as $guild ) {
    echo "Guild: " . $guild['guildname'] . "\n";
}
```

Which gets me:

```
Guild: Server Name 
Guild: Server Name
```

and if you want to really up your debugging game you'd want to look at using something like [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/) and an IDE that can plug into it properly.

Comment: If I do what you just did with having the json_deocde() with the true it doesn't work and gives me the error I had shown in the origional post. If It matters I am pulling that json from a database.

Comment: When I use var_dump() on $userdata['guilds'] which is the guilds json that I pull from the database it just has ?? for the icons...

Comment: Yea still cant figure this out at all ive tried multiple ways with pulling it from the db but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $guildData = $stmt->fecth(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
> ```

Assuming you fix the typo `fecth` to `fetch`, this line will return [an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters). For debugging purposes, when you write

```
var_dump($guildData);
```

after that line, you will see something like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["guilds"]=>
  string(32) "[{"id": 1, "guildname": "Ser...."
}
```

However, the [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function expects a string, not an array.

To fix it you simply access the `guilds` field from the array:

```
$guildData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // returns an array
$jsonData = $guildData['guilds'];            // get the 'guilds' field
$extracted = json_decode($jsonData, true);   // JSON -> array
var_dump($extracted);                        // just for debugging
```

This will fix the "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error message. You also might have to take a look at [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) to see if you have configured everything the right way to get the content in the correct format.

Comment: Yea I had fixed the fetch when I had went over it again, but still the same thing. I had someone walk me through previously with the charset and all the stuff for the database etc.